# How (or which) filter methods we can use to check if thete is no direct relationship between features and target

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, correlation, data-analysis

one approach of feature selection is filter method.

In this method we check 2 things:

1. relation between feature i and target. we want to preserve only features that influence the target
2. relation between feature i and feature j. we want to remove redundant features

There can be a situation where there is no direct relation between feature i to target, but there is relation between combination of 2 or more features to the target.

from my understanding, all the filter methods checks direct relationship (1 or 2) between feature i and target (and they don't check relation between multiple features to target)

1. Am I right ?
2. Are there any filter methods to check non-direct relation between features and target ? (or we must use wrapper or hybrid methods to select features when there is no direct relation ) ?